# Local storage stores string once and will not change

Tags: javascript

I have this function where it shows the search listing in a card (recent searches). When I search something, it stores successfully in local storage but when I search another item the listing (recent search) doesn't update. Even after page refresh, the same first search stays in the card and won't update at all. Can anyone see whats happening and how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Javascript:

```
function customDeal1() {

  var recentSearch = document.querySelector('#search').value;
  var HighScore = localStorage.getItem('highScore');

var matchArray = findDeals(HighScore, name).slice(0,1);
  const html = matchArray.map(place => {
    const regex = new RegExp(HighScore);
    const nameName = place.name.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${HighScore}</span>`);
         var shop = place.url.replace(/(centra)|[^]/g, '$1').replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase());
         var shop1 = place.url.replace(/(tesco)|[^]/g, '$1').replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase());
         var shop2 = place.url.replace(/(aldi)|[^]/g, '$1').replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase());
         var shop3 = place.url.replace(/(lidl)|[^]/g, '$1').replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase());
         var shop4 = place.url.replace(/(supervalu)|[^]/g, '$1').replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase());
    return `

            <img src="${place.imgurl}" alt="Drink Image">
            <h5>${nameName}</h5>
            <p>${(place.price)} ${shop} ${shop1} ${shop2} ${shop3} ${shop4}</p>

    `;
  }).join('') || '<li> No Searches Found </li>';
  deal2.innerHTML = html; 

if(!localStorage.getItem('highScore') || localStorage.getItem('highScore').length === 0){
  localStorage.setItem('highScore', recentSearch);
}

};
const deal2 = document.querySelector('.deal1');
setInterval(customDeal1,5000);
```

Comment: That's because you're only calling `localStorage.setItem()` when it is not set or it has a length of 0. Once you have set it, this statement will always return false and therefore you cannot update the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in this line

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('highScore') || localStorage.getItem('highScore').length === 0){
  localStorage.setItem('highScore', recentSearch);
}
```

it works at first because local storage is empty but once you execute the code 
recentSearch will be stored in local storage which means the line above will be skipped
to fix this you will have to delete recentSearch from local storage before the line above or just save the data without the if statement because local storage overwrite data

Comment: Ah okay. But without the if statement it doesn't survive past the 2nd refresh.

Comment: try and change the `localStorage.getItem('highScore').length ==0 for  length>0 `

Comment: or add this line before the if statement `localStorage.clear()`

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
        function customDeal1() {

        var recentSearch = document.querySelector('#search').value;
        var HighScore = localStorage.getItem('highScore');
        deal2.innerHTML = recentSearch;

        // delete the conditions : if(!localStorage.getItem('highScore') ...
        localStorage.setItem('highScore', recentSearch);

    };
    const deal2 = document.querySelector('.deal1');
    setInterval(customDeal1, 5000);
```